# How to refer rails session from grape api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-grape, grape-api

I try to refer rails session from grape api.

I used grape_session library(https://github.com/faber-lotto/grape_session).

And I refer same name Rails session parameter　from grape api.

But session of grape API is null.

Do you know why.

I configured following grape_session.

```
class Base < Grape::API
～～～～
include GrapeSession::Ext::API
GrapeSession::Middleware::EnvSetup.settings( {
  signed_cookie_salt: 'signed cookie',
  encrypted_cookie_salt: 'encrypted cookie',
  encrypted_signed_cookie_salt: 'signed encrypted cookie',
  secret_token: 'secret_token',
  secret_key_base: 'secret base',
  cookies_serializer: :json,

  session_options: {
      # Rails specific ActionDispatch::Compatibilityy
      key: 'test_rails',    # specific key of session_store.rb
      # Rack::Session::Abstract::ID specific
      domain: 'localhost:3000',
      path:  '/',
      expire_after: 2592000,
      secure: false,
      httponly: true,
      defer: false,
      renew: false,
    }
} )

get '/test' do
  session[:password]
end
```